# Performance of Cassandra 1.0

Tags: performance, cassandra

Is there a limit for column families per cluster/keyspace beyond which cassandra performance will decrease significantly?
I know we've had some problems with earlier versions, and somehow reducing number of column families solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-1-0-improved-memory-and-disk-space-management which says:

> "Cassandra 1.0 only uses one memtable setting:
>   memtable_total_space_in_mb (found in cassandra.yaml), which defaults
>   to 1/3 of your JVM heap. Cassandra manages this space across all your
>   ColumnFamilies and flushes memtables to disk as needed. This has been
>   tested to work across hundreds or even thousands of ColumnFamilies. "

See also

- http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration
- http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable